# Call to a member function union() on a non-object in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create pagination using union of two tables, but get the following error:

> Call to a member function union() on a non-object

```
$query1=Mobile::find()->select('video')->all();
$query2=Tablet::find()->select('video')->all();
$count=Mobile::find()->count();
$query = (new Query)
    ->select('*')
    ->from([
        $query1->union($query2),
    ])
    ->limit(3);
```

How can i union two tables in this framework?

Comment: $query1, used as subquery in $query (from method), is not an ActiveQuery istance but is an array of Mobile models. You should declare $query1 as Mobile::find()->select('video'), without calling all() at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$query1=Mobile::find()->select('video');
$query2=Tablet::find()->select('video');

$unionQuery = $query1->union($query2)->limit(3)->all();
```